# How to use fun.data (stat_summary)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, weighted-average

I want to use the `fun.data` option in ggplot2. What I whant to do is a graph showing the percentage (weighted) of people that chose more than say 4 points in a question of a survey.

If I wanted to do the same graphic but without weighting the people, I would do:

```
ggplot(database, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(stat='summary', fun.y=function1)
```

where:

```
function1 <- function(x){
  value=sum(x>=4)/sum(x)
  names(value)='y'
  value
}
```

But how can I do it for the weighed case? I tried this option but it didn't work:

```
ggplot(database, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(stat='summary', fun.data=function2)
```

where:

```
function2 <- function(base){
  value=sum((x>=4)*base$weight)/sum(base$weight)
  result=c(value, value, value)
  names(result)=c('y','ymax', 'ymin')
  result
}
```

However, it doesn't recognize `base$weight`. Why?

Comment: could you provide a subset of your data using dput()?

Comment: You should aggregate outside of ggplot2.

Comment: @Roland, how would you do it using aggregate? I face the same problem as in ggplot, that it only accepts  one variable...

Comment: Provide some example data and I could show you. Or you search SO for `aggregate`, `ddply`, `dplyr`, `data.table`, ...